# Outer for-loop of nested for-loop will be ignored on execution

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, nested, initialization

unfortunenately I got stuck on a basic for-loop during a FPGA co-design.
I would like to iterate through a pixel array. Therefor I would like to use the following c-code:

```
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480 

...

int y = 0;
int x = 0;

for(; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    for(; x < WIDTH; x++)
    printf("X: %4i  Y: %4i Color: %x \n", x, y, (0x3FF & x) << 11 | (0x1FF & y) << 2 | col);
```

The debugging terminal output is the following:

```
X:    0  Y:    0 Color: 1 
X:    1  Y:    0 Color: 801 
X:    2  Y:    0 Color: 1001 
X:    3  Y:    0 Color: 1801 
...
```

I have no idea why the outer loop will be completely ignored and the inner one works properly? The outer-loop will stay at the index value "0", which shouldnt be the case.

If I initialize the loop indizes inside of the for-loop condition it will works as expected.

```
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480 

...

int y;
int x;

for(y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    for(x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
    printf("X: %4i  Y: %4i Color: %x \n", x, y, (0x3FF & x) << 11 | (0x1FF & y) << 2 | col);
```

Whats the reason that the first code-snippet doesnt work?
(compiled with gcc and also some vivado integrated compiler).

Comment: *I have no idea why the outer loop will be completely ignored and the inner one works properly* - why do you think it is? There are many thing hidden in your `...`

Comment: `for(; x < WIDTH; x++)` What is `x` going to be 2nd iteration of `y` loop?

Comment: And yes, you just initialize `x` once, but you want it to get initialized for every `y`.

Comment: This was the whole main function.

Comment: @EugeneSh this does not explain why the outer loop will be ignore, right ?

Comment: You haven't demonstrated yet what you mean by "ignored". It's the inner one which will be "ignored", and since you have your print in it, you just don't see it.

Comment: @LamdLamdaLamda The `...` in the shown code tells me that this is *not* the whole `main` function.

Comment: Or the asker is a time traveler using some future version of C or C++ that supports variadic `main`.

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a closer look at the loops:

```
for(; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    for(; x < WIDTH; x++)
```

First you enter the outer loop, where `y` equals `0`. Then you enter the inner loop which will iterate `x` from `0` to `WIDTH`.

Then the inner loop end, and the outer loop iterates, with `y` becoming `1`. Then you get to the inner loop again, where ***`x` is equal to `WIDTH`***. So the inner loop will never iterate again, letting the outer loop iterate until `y` reaches `HEIGHT`.

You need to reset `x` every time you start over with the inner loop:

```
for(; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    for(x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
```

This would have been *very* obvious if you just tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your inner for loop, x will have the value of WIDTH. Any subsequence iterations of this loop, x will start at WIDTH. You would need to reset the value of x to 0 each time. That is why your second snippet works, you are resetting x to 0.

```
for (; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    for ( x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x )
        // ...
```